# visual studio 2012 C#: application folders

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, directory

I'm developing an application in C# with Visual Studio 2012. I need to have an application folder that stores some files created by the application, and I also need to check if this folder is empty or not.
For example, I need that my application has a folder named "properties", in which the application stores some xml files that describes a property. The application, at startup, must check this folder to see if there are some files into, and if yes, do something...
I want that, when I debug my application in Debug mode with Visual Studio, I can do this check about folder, but I do not know how to create it...
I know that, in Installation and distribution project of Visual Studio, I can define some folders that the application creates when it will be installed in some machine, but how can I do some tests without having the installation project but only debugging my application?

Thanks for your help

Comment: `System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory` and `System.IO.Directory.Exists` are your friend. You don't need the installation routine for creating folders as long as you don't want to do this within your program's folder (where the exe is installed), where your program might not have enough access rights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use one of the predefined folders specified by the [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) enum

These folders are identified by this enum to remove the difference in real paths due to different operating systems. And this is a sample showing how to create a specific folder for your application through code

```
string comAppData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData));
string myAppFolder = Path.Combine(comAppData, "MyAppDataFolder");
if (!Directory.Exists(myAppFolder)
     Directory.CreateDirectory(myAppFolder);

// Now you can write to this application folder 

string myPropertyFile = Path.Combine(myAppFolder, "myAppProperty.properties");
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(myPropertyFile))
{
     // your code to write data.... 
}
```

This example (running on Windows7) checks and eventually creates a directory called `MyAppDataFolder` in `C:\programdata` folder.

Comment: Thanks Steve but there is some problem. First time I run the code, it executes the  createDirectory(), but directory does not exists on filesystem...second time I run the code, the directory exists, but I don't see it in the filesystem...I run only code for folder creation and commented the part about propertyfile

Comment: C:\programdata is an hidden directory. If you want to enable the visualization of hidden folders see here http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-vista/